# MSDTC Configuration Automation

Tags: entity-framework, configuration, transactions, msdtc

We are developing a large scale business application using most new technologies through .NET 3.5 and we are using EF as DataAccessLayer in our architecture in addition to Transaction management which automatically uses System.Transaction and MSTC.
We need to deploy this application by ClickOnce method for over 300 end-user in each customer's organizations,however we could not be able to do this task ourself or training end-user to configure their MSDTC settings for supporting System.Transaction,really it's impossible for minimum 200-300 users up to 500 or 600,therefore we need a solution to configure these clients MSDTC engine automatically and providing this solution by automating in ClickOnce deployment, Setup packages and so on.
Is there any way?, or others experiencing like this problem to automating MSDTC configuration on clients such as by manually editing Registry, PowerShell scripts or likewise?

Any help or solution would be grateful.